# How to use Stream.flatMap()?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have `Stream<SortedSet<String>>`, and I want to have just a `Stream<String>`. I tried using `flatMap()` but it did not work since it cannot flat Stream of Sortedset.

```
String productName = "p1";
Set<Product> products = new HashSet<>();
products.add(new Product(productName));
Stream<SortedSet<String>> sortedSetStream = products.stream().map(p -> Util.getProductNames(p) );
```

Answer (score 5):

To obtain a stream of all objects from a stream of collection of those objects you need to *flatten* the collections. Any collection can be transformed onto a stream:

```
Stream<SortedSet<String>> sortedSetStream = products.stream().map(p -> Util.getProductNames(p) );
Stream<String> ss = sortedSetStream.flatMap( s -> s.stream() );
```

or (if you prefer method reference):

```
Stream<String> ss = sortedSetStream.flatMap( Collection::stream );
```